# Django: Pagination ListView and return json

Tags: django

I have this ListView that paginates the context, but i want to add also car types in my context, for that i need to built it in json which i don't know how, or is any other way around this, any help would be very much appreciated.

```py
class CarListView(ListView):
    model = Car
    template_name = 'listings.html'
    context_object_name = 'cars'
    ordering = ['-created']
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        print(context)
        paginator = context['paginator']
        page_numbers_range = 10  # Display 5 page numbers
        max_index = len(paginator.page_range)

        page = self.request.GET.get('page')
        print(self.request)
        current_page = int(page) if page else 1

        start_index = int((current_page - 1) / page_numbers_range) * page_numbers_range
        end_index = start_index + page_numbers_range
        if end_index >= max_index:
            end_index = max_index

        page_range = paginator.page_range[start_index:end_index]
        # context['page_range'] = page_range
        # return context
        cars = Car.objects.all()[:10]
        car_types = CarType.objects.all()
        context = {'cars': cars, 'car_types': car_types}
        return context
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding your entire context on the last statement....

Change

`context = {'cars': cars, 'car_types': car_types}`

for

`context['cars']=cars
context['car_types']=car_types`